# Xvfb error on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running Xvfb on my Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS VPS (Linode). For some reason I'm getting the following errors and can't really get around them.

```
AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
(EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!
```

Any advice?

Comment: This question refers to Ubuntu, but for Centos6, i fixed it using `yum install mesa-dri-drivers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install libgl1-mesa-dri:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

and xont:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
```

Comment: That seemed to solve most of the problems. Only this one remains:

[dix] Could not init font path element /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType, removing from list!

Comment: @jorde I update answer

Comment: I actually had those installed already and rerunning the command didn't help. But as this remaining error doesn't actually seem to affect my scripts anymore I'll lt it be for now. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should solve your last issue:

```
sudo apt-get install defoma x-ttcidfont-conf
```